# Update struct field

Tags: elisp

Is there a more ergonomic way to apply a function to a field in a struct in Elisp?

Say I have the following:

```
(cl-defstruct stack xs)

(defvar stack (make-stack :xs '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

Is there an easy way to apply functions to the `:xs` field. I'd like an API like this:

```
(update-field :xs stack (lambda (xs)
                          (cl-map 'list #'1+ '(1 2 3 4 5))))
```

Does anyone know if this exists?

**Update:**
I'm looking for a way to DRY up the calls to `(stack-xs stack)` (see below). What I'm looking for is more similar to something like [`Map.update`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update/4) from Elixir.

```
(setf (stack-xs stack) (cl-map 'list #'1+ (stack-xs stack)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by writing a macro, `struct/update`:

```
(defmacro struct/update (type field f xs)
  "Apply F to FIELD in XS, which is a struct of TYPE.
This is immutable."
  (let ((copier (->> type
                     symbol-name
                     (string/prepend "copy-")
                     intern))
        (accessor (->> field
                       symbol-name
                       (string/prepend (string/concat (symbol-name type) "-"))
                       intern)))
    `(let ((copy (,copier ,xs)))
       (setf (,accessor copy) (funcall ,f (,accessor copy)))
       copy)))
```

I use this macro as such:

```
(defun set/add (x xs)
  "Add X to set XS."
  (struct/update set
                 xs
                 (lambda (table)
                   (let ((table-copy (ht-copy table)))
                     (ht-set table-copy x 10)
                     table-copy))
                 xs))
```

Which will update the following struct:

```
(cl-defstruct set xs)
```

Comment: Code available here in case anyone's interested: https://github.com/wpcarro/struct.el

Answer (score 1):

The `cl-defstruct` macro creates slot accessors of the form `NAME-SLOT` where `NAME` is the struct type name, and `SLOT` is the slot name. Using your example, you can set the `xs` slot using `setf` with the slot accessor like this:

```
(cl-defstruct stack xs)
(defvar st (make-stack :xs '(1 2 3 4 5)))
(setf (stack-xs st) (cl-map 'list #'1+ (stack-xs st)))
(stack-xs st)
```

The final line above returns `'(2 3 4 5 6)`.

**Update:** a downside of the `setf` call shown above is that the slot accessor has to be used twice, once to read the current value and then again to update it to the new value. You can use `cl-callf` to DRY it up:

```
(cl-callf (lambda (p) (cl-map 'list #'1+ p)) (stack-xs st))
```

Alternatively you could wrap the `setf` call within a new method defined on the `stack` type using `cl-defmethod`, perhaps like this:

```
(cl-defmethod stack-update ((s stack) f slot)
  "Update SLOT in stack S by applying F.
F is passed one argument, the current value of SLOT,
and is expected to return a new value for SLOT."
  (let ((sl (if (keywordp slot) (intern (substring (symbol-name slot) 1)) slot)))
    (setf (cl-struct-slot-value 'stack sl s) (funcall f (cl-struct-slot-value 'stack sl s)))))
```

You can then call `stack-update` like this:

```
(stack-update st #'(lambda (p) (cl-map 'list #'1+ p)) :xs)
```

or equivalently:

```
(stack-update st (apply-partially 'cl-map 'list #'1+) 'xs)
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that I know how to update struct fields using `setf`. I'm looking for something more like `updatef` if `updatef` existed. Do you know of anything. `setf` is like `Map.set` and `updatef` would be more like a `Map.update`.

Comment: Perhaps the update to my answer addresses your concern about `setf`?